# Why Celery does not embed a timestamp into the queued message?

Tags: python, celery, distributed

I was trying to obtain the wait time of a Celery queued task. As far as I know, I can do so via the Event stream published by the Celery workers. In curiosity, why a simple timestamp is not embedded in the queued task? Is this related to distributed system design?

NOTE: celery==3.0.12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rely on physical wall time in distributed systems so such a field would not be very useful.

With event streams this is different since the `task-started` and `task-succeeded` timestamps are both from the same clock source.

That said, there are times when an approximate value can be useful so you can add this
information yourself:

```
add.apply_async((4, 4), headers={'time_sent': time.time()})
```

You have access to the message headers in the task (but note that this requires Celery 3.1):

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    print('Approximate queue time: {0}'.format(
        time.time() - self.request.headers.get('time_sent', 0),
    ))
    return x + y
```

Comment: What I'm actually doing is setting up a AWS CloudWatch custom metric that monitors the wait time of tasks in the queue. So, shall I add a header like what you've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: You can do that, or you can collect the information using a custom event monitor (Userguide -> Monitoring)

Comment: How to pass a custom header with celery beat? I know about the [`options`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields) field, but its value is set at startup and then does not change.